# SharePoint Timer Job targeted at specific web application?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to deploy a custom SPJobDefinition that I want to run against a specific web application. I thought I could to this by using the web-application scoped base constructor for SPJobDefinition and passing in the web application that I want. I'm doing this in a web application feature's FeatureActivated event receiver:

```
            TestJob Job = new TestJob("Test", webApp);
            // TODO: change the schedule to run nightly; one time for testing purposes only
            SPOneTimeSchedule schedule = new SPOneTimeSchedule(DateTime.Now);
            TestJob.Schedule = schedule;                
            TestJob.Update();
```

Here's the constructor for the job itself:

```
    public TestJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)
        : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
    {
        this.Title = jobName;
    }
```

It seems that the job in running against all web applications regardless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Small error there: you need to cast your Timer Job definition as such and not as your custom `ChangeRequestRollup`.

So do the following for your feature receiver:

```
SPJobDefinition changeRequestRollupJob = new ChangeRequestRollup("Devon PMO Change Requests Report", webApp);
// install timer job, on a daily scheduleSPDailySchedule dailySchedule = new SPDailySchedule
{
    BeginHour = 07,
    BeginMinute = 11,
    BeginSecond = 00,
    EndHour = 09,
    EndMinute = 12,
    EndSecond = 00
};

changeRequestRollupJob.Schedule = dailySchedule;
changeRequestRollupJob.Update();
```

I'm also not sure about your `SPOneTimeSchedule` so I modified it to use `SPDailySchedule`. Other than that it should work just fine like you did it.